# Sort List of Strings with Localization

Tags: java, sorting, collections, localization, locale

I want to sort below List of strings as per user locale

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
      "Äbc", "äbc", "Àbc", "àbc", "Abc", "abc", "ABC"
    );
```

For different user locale sort output should be different as per there locale.

How to sort above list as per user locale ?

I tried

```
Collections.sort(words , String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

But this is not working for localization, so how to pass locale parameter to `Collections.sort()` or is there any other efficient way ?

Comment: look out for Comparable interface

Comment: your output is [Abc, abc, ABC, Àbc, àbc, Äbc, äbc] after sorting. isn't this correct? i think sorting is already based on 1-alphabetical order 2-locale order.

Comment: Sorting should consider base char , accent , case , bits. So output should be [abc, Abc, ABC, àbc, Àbc, äbc, Äbc] for FRANCE locale

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use a sort with a custom Comparator. See the [Collator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

```
Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(locale);
coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Collections.sort(words, coll);
```

The collator is a comparator and can be passed directly to the `Collections.sort(...)` method.

Comment: @kerem why did you remove the attribution?

Comment: Jan sorry if i did something wrong. Collator.PRIMARY is discussed in the next answer with details, and it is obvious that you get the idea from @Bhesh.

Answer (score 30):

I think this what you should be using - [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html)

> The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison. You use this class to build searching and sorting routines for natural language text.

Do something as follows in your comparator -

```
public int compare(String arg1, Sting arg2) {
    Collator usCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US); //Your locale here
    usCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    return usCollator.compare(arg1, arg2);
}
```

And pass an instance of the comparator the `Collections.sort` method.

**Update**

Like @Jan Dvorak said, it actually is a comparator, so you can just create it's intance with the desired locale, set the strength and pass it the sort method:

```
Collactor usCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.US); //Your locale here
usCollator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY); //desired strength
Collections.sort(yourList, usCollator);
```

Comment: What does Collator.PRIMARY will do ?

Comment: @RahulAgrawal: It's the strength of comparision. Please read the documentation, you will find a detailed explanation there. That's where I borrowed the example from.

Comment: The collator IS a comparator. I just found out.

Comment: @JanDvorak Ohh Collator is a Comparator, which does support I18N .. :)

Comment: @RahulAgrawal I admit I shouldn't be surprised that a Collator is a Comparator :-)

Comment: The Comparator with Locale.GERMAN doesn't sort correctly. Our rules are somewhat complicated, but nonetheless.

Answer (score 9):

```
List<MODEL> ulke = new ArrayList<MODEL>();

    Collections.sort(ulke, new Comparator<MODEL>() {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr-TR"));
        @Override
        public int compare(MODEL o1, MODEL o2) {
            return collator.compare(o1.getULKEAD(), o2.getULKEAD());
        }
    });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.