# Sorting String with non-western characters

Tags: java, string, sorting, locale

I wanted to print sorted Polish names of all available languages.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Tmp
{
  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("pl","PL"));
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    ArrayList<String> langs = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Locale loc: locales) {
      String  lng = loc.getDisplayLanguage();
      if(!lng.trim().equals("") && ! langs.contains(lng)){
        langs.add(lng);
      }
    }
    Collections.sort(langs);
    for(String str: langs){
      System.out.println(str);
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately I have issue with the sorting part.
The output is:

```
:
:
kataloński
koreański
litewski
macedoński
:
:
węgierski
włoski
łotewski
```

Unfortunately in Polish `ł` comes after `l` and before `m` so the output should be:

```
:
:
kataloński
koreański
litewski
łotewski
macedoński
:
:
węgierski
włoski
```

How can I accomplish that? Is there an universal non-language-dependent method (say I now want to display this and sort in another language with another sorting rules).

Comment: have u checked this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889760/sort-list-of-strings-with-localization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass a Collator to the sort method:

```
// sort according to default locale
Collections.sort(langs, Collator.getInstance());
```

The default sort order is defined by the Unicode codepoints in the string, and that's not the correct alphabetical order in any language.

Answer (score 11):

try

```
Collections.sort(langs, Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl", "PL")));
```

it will produce

```
...
litewski
łotewski
...
```

see Collator API for details

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`java.text.Collator.newInstance(Locale)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29). You need to supply the Polish locale in your case. Collators implement the `Comparator` interface, so you can use that in sort APIs and in sorted datastructures like `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately in Polish ł comes after l and before m so the output
>   should be:

You can define your own [`Compararable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) or [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) interface.

Or also this might help you:

- [Sort List of Strings with
  Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889760/sort-list-of-strings-with-localization)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
val polishCollator = yourCollection.sortedWith(Comparator { s1, s2 ->
            Collator.getInstance(Locale("pl", "PL")).compare(s1,s2)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'am dealing with the same problem. I found that the local collector solution works fine for android 7.0, but does not on earlier android versions.
I've implemented the following algorithm. It is pretty fast ( I sort more than 3000 strings) and does it on earlier android versions too.

```
public class SortBasedOnName implements Comparator {

    private Map<Character, Integer> myCharMap;
    private final static Map<Character, Integer>myPolCharTable = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    static {
        myPolCharTable.put(' ',0x0020);
        myPolCharTable.put('!',0x0021);
        myPolCharTable.put('"',0x0022);


        myPolCharTable.put('a',0x0040);
        myPolCharTable.put('ą',0x0041);
        myPolCharTable.put('b',0x0042);
        myPolCharTable.put('c',0x0043);
        myPolCharTable.put('ć',0x0044);


        myPolCharTable.put('{',0x0066);
        myPolCharTable.put('|',0x0067);
        myPolCharTable.put('}',0x0068);
    }

    public SortBasedOnName() {}

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

        Dictionary dd1 = (Dictionary) o1;
        Dictionary dd2 = (Dictionary) o2;

    return strCompareWithDiacritics(dd1.getOriginal(), dd2.getOriginal());
    }

    private  int strCompareWithDiacritics(String s1, String s2) {

        int i = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int length =0;

        s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
        s2 = s2.toLowerCase();
        if (s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            result = 1;
            length = s2.length();
        } else if (s1.length() < s2.length()) {
            result = -1;
            length = s1.length();
        } else if (s1.length() == s2.length()) {
            result = 0;
            length = s1.length();
        }

        try {
            while (i <length) {
                if (myPolCharTable.get(s1.charAt(i)) > myPolCharTable.get(s2.charAt(i))) {
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                } else if (myPolCharTable.get(s1.charAt(i)) < myPolCharTable.get(s2.charAt(i))) {
                    result = -1;
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```