# How to sort by local strings letter sensitive?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Suppose I have list of words like

```
a, b, c, ą, ć, z, ż
```

I want to be sorted with polish locale like:

```
a, ą, b, c, ć, z, ż
```

Is it possible to achieve?

**UPDATE:**

Suppose I have to sort list by two object parameters and also using collator.
For one property I can use:

```
val collator = Collator.getInstance(context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale)

myList.sortedWith(compareBy(collator,  { it.lastName.toLowerCase() }))
```

How to add to this also to sort by `firstName`? (so for example if there will be two same `lastName` then sort them by `firstName`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518502/sorting-string-with-non-western-characters?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Try something like this:

```
val list = arrayListOf("a", "b", "c", "ą", "ć", "z", "ż")
val coll = Collator.getInstance(Locale("pl","PL"))
coll.strength = Collator.PRIMARY
Collections.sort(list, coll)
println(list)
```

Update:

Make your object implement Comparable:

```
override fun compareTo(other: YourObject): Int {
    val coll = Collator.getInstance(Locale("pl","PL"))
    coll.strength = Collator.PRIMARY
    val lastNameCompareValue =  coll.compare(lastName?.toLowerCase(Locale("pl","PL")),other.lastName?.toLowerCase(Locale("pl","PL")))
    if (lastNameCompareValue != 0) {
        return lastNameCompareValue
    }
    val firstNameCompareValue =  coll.compare(firstName?.toLowerCase(Locale("pl","PL")),other.firstName?.toLowerCase(Locale("pl","PL")))
    return firstNameCompareValue
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks, can you see my updated question? Maybe you have idea how to combine this answer that you gave me previously

Comment: @Konrad you should implement comparable interface in your object and do that logic in the compareTo method

Comment: Still not sure how exactly this can help me - i still cannot apply sorting by two properties and collator to them

Comment: That's good solution. The only thing about it is that what when i need other Collator? Normally it is provied by Context but it will be hard to have context in some data class object that has this Comparable implemented

Comment: @Konrad you can get context in by creating an Application class (if you haven't any) and getting the instance from there, so you can do something like `val context = MyAppClass.getInstance()`