# How to sort list of objects by two properties and collator

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have to sort list of object by lastName and firstName (if case there is the same lastName for multiple objects). I must also apply Collator to those.

Suppose I can do that for one property:

```
val collator = Collator.getInstance(context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale)

myList.sortedWith(compareBy(collator, { it.lastName.toLowerCase() }))
```

But is it possible to apply also to that another restriction to also sort by firstName?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52283610/how-to-sort-by-local-strings-letter-sensitive

Comment: Thanks, see the answer here - for me most convenient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add another sort criteria with `thenBy`:

```
val comparator =
        compareBy(collator) { p: Person -> p.lastName.toLowerCase() }
                .thenBy(collator) { p: Person -> p.firstName.toLowerCase() }
val result = myList.sortedWith(comparator)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would just be to concatenate the two properties in the selector lambda:

```
myList.sortedWith(
    compareBy(collator) { "${it.lastName} ${it.firstName}".toLowerCase() }
)
```