# Sorting countries in alphabetically ascending order in all languages

Tags: java, android, sorting, java-8

I am developing an android application for market survey. On the registration page I have a spinner to list down all the countries and I am using the function `Arrays.sort()` to sort the list in alphabetically ascending order. I kept my tablet language as 'English' and obtained an alphabetically sorted list.

However, when I changed the tablet language to Portuguese, the list being displayed is not sorted (*please see the screenshot attached*). The language has some alphabets different from the English language. I know that java performs sorting based on ASCII code of the characters. But is there any other way to obtain a sorted result, irrespective of the language being used.

[image]

Comment: It looks like your list is indeed sorted based on the language. It's only that the character code of Á is greater than that of Z. You might want to consider this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889868/578759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for a [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) with a specific chosen `Locale` (like English, since you've stated that it then works correctly).

So you can use something like this:

```
Collections.sort(yourArray, Collator.getInstance(new Locale("en", "US")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to expect some seemingly arbitrariness when sorting letters in a locale who's language does not include those letters. A collation might specify an ordering but not follow rules that you would like it to. For example, in US English, what is the correct ordering between ñ and ณ?

One option is the have a separate list in each language that you want to sort by, using only letters in that language. (If that doesn't work, then, once you've gone that far, you could have a fixed ordering in each list.)