# Android sort String Portuguese Locale

Tags: android, string, sorting, collections, locale

have array string 
["água","acidente","ajuda","alergia"]
when use

```
Collections.sort(listName, new Comparator<Language>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Language lhs, Language rhs) {
                return compareStringWithLocale(lhs.getName(), rhs.getName());
            }
        });

public int compareStringWithLocale(String arg1, String arg2) {
        Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pt_BR"));
        collator.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
        return collator.compare(arg1, arg2);
    }
```

output is ["acidente","água","ajuda","alergia"]

Expected is ["acidente","ajuda","alergia","água"]

how to fix it
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort List of Strings with Localization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889760/sort-list-of-strings-with-localization)

Comment: yes, i found solution in this topic  and use same solution but not work for portuguese (Brazil) language

Comment: Hi, did you try this solution?




Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(locale);
coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Collections.sort(words, coll);