# How to reduce a string to ASCII 7 characters for indexing purposes?

Tags: indexing, ascii, non-ascii-characters, transliteration

I am working on an application which must index certain sentences. Currently using Java and PostgreSQL. The sentences may be in several languages like French and Spanish using accents and other non-ASCII symbols.

For each word I want to create an index-able equivalent so that a user can perform a search insensitive to accents (transliteration). For example, when the user searches "nacion" it must find it even if the original word stored by the application was "Naci**ó**n".

What could be the best strategy for this? I am not necessarily restricted only to PostgreSQL, nor the internal indexed value needs to have any similarity with the original word. Ideally, it should be a generic solution for converting any Unicode string into an ASCII string insensitive to case and accents.

So far I am using a custom function shown below which naively just replaces some letters with ASCII equivalents before storing the indexed value and does the same on query strings.

```
public String toIndexableASCII (String sStrIn) {
  if (sStrIn==null) return null;
  int iLen = sStrIn.length();
  if (iLen==0) return sStrIn;
  StringBuilder sStrBuff = new StringBuilder(iLen);
  String sStr = sStrIn.toUpperCase();

  for (int c=0; c<iLen; c++) {
    switch (sStr.charAt(c)) {
      case 'Á':
      case 'À':
      case 'Ä':
      case 'Â':
      case 'Å':
      case 'Ã':
        sStrBuff.append('A');
        break;
      case 'É':
      case 'È':
      case 'Ë':
      case 'Ê':
        sStrBuff.append('E');
        break;
      case 'Í':
      case 'Ì':
      case 'Ï':
      case 'Î':
        sStrBuff.append('I');
        break;
      case 'Ó':
      case 'Ò':
      case 'Ö':
      case 'Ô':
      case 'Ø':
        sStrBuff.append('O');
        break;
      case 'Ú':
      case 'Ù':
      case 'Ü':
      case 'Û':
        sStrBuff.append('U');
        break;
      case 'Æ':
        sStrBuff.append('E');
        break;
      case 'Ñ':
        sStrBuff.append('N');
        break;
      case 'Ç':
        sStrBuff.append('C');
        break;
      case 'ß':
        sStrBuff.append('B');
        break;
      case (char)255:
        sStrBuff.append('_');
        break;
      default:
        sStrBuff.append(sStr.charAt(c));
    }
  }

  return sStrBuff.toString();
}
```

Comment: Interpreting the bytes as ASCII 7 would not provide the "information loss" that I want to achieve. I want "coraçón" to be the same as "coracon" so that it doesn´t matter whether the user puts the accents or not when searching. I do not need a spelling or proximity checker like Google "did you mean ...?" But I do need "é" == "e".

Comment: The mapping you are asking about is called "transliteration."

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question to add transliteration, also helped me to Google a few goodmatches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String s = "Nación";

    String x = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s.length());
    for (char c : x.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.getType(c) != Character.NON_SPACING_MARK) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(s); // Nación
    System.out.println(sb.toString()); // Nacion
```

How this works:
It splits up international characters to [NFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Combining_and_precomposed_characters) decomposition (`ó` becomes `o◌́`), then strips the combining diacritical marks.

`Character.NON_SPACING_MARK` contains combining diacritical marks (Unicode calls it Bidi Class [NSM [Non-Spacing Mark]](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/bidiclass/NSM)).

Comment: If you want to just **compare** two strings, as opposed to storing canonicalized versions, a more robust solution is available; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889760/sort-list-of-strings-with-localization

Answer (score 1):

The one obvious improvement for your current code: use a `Map<Character, Character>` that you **prefill** with your mappings.

And then simply check if that Map has a mapping; of so; use that; otherwise use the original character.

And as Androbin explains, there are special maps that do not rely on objects, but work with primitive types, like this [trove](http://java-performance.info/primitive-types-collections-trove-library/). So, depending on your solution and requirements; you could look into that.

Comment: Thankfully, there is Map#getOrDefault

Comment: I recommend a primitive Map for efficiency

Comment: there are for example FastUtil, HPPC, Koloboke and Trove