# "Đ" sorts improperly when sorting Vietnamese text using Java

Tags: java, sorting, text, localization

Sorting does not seem to work for this Vietnamese text `Đ`.

I am trying to sort on `wardName`. A string which contains `Đ`, which is sorted improperly.

Issue is with this string: `wardName":"X. ĐA PHƯỚC`

```
{"cityId":11,"cityName":"T. AN GIANG","districts":[{"districtId":135,"districtName":"H. AN PHÚ","wards":[{"wardId":"2505","wardName":"TT. AN PHÚ"},{"wardId":"2509","wardName":"TT. LONG BÌNH"},{"wardId":"2507","wardName":"X. KHÁNH AN"},{"wardId":"2508","wardName":"X. KHÁNH BÌNH"},{"wardId":"2510","wardName":"X. NHƠN HỘI"},{"wardId":"2511","wardName":"X. PHÚ HỘI"},{"wardId":"2513","wardName":"X. PHÚ HỮU"},{"wardId":"2512","wardName":"X. PHƯỚC HƯNG"},{"wardId":"2514","wardName":"X. QUỐC THÁI"},{"wardId":"2515","wardName":"X. VĨNH HẬU"},{"wardId":"2516","wardName":"X. VĨNH HỘI ĐÔNG"},{"wardId":"2517","wardName":"X. VĨNH LỘC"},{"wardId":"2518","wardName":"X. VĨNH TRƯỜNG"},{"wardId":"2506","wardName":"X. ĐA PHƯỚC"}]}
```

`{"wardId":"2506","wardName":"X. ĐA PHƯỚC"}`: This should come before the target string, but it displays this at the end:
`{"wardId":"2507","wardName":"X. KHÁNH AN"}`

Issue seems to be caused by the `Đ` character.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889760/sort-list-of-strings-with-localization might be useful?

Comment: @Dinesh please format your code blocks.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code the data seen above.

Comment: As @Gavin wrote, you can't sort efficiently many languages with the standard sort functions. If you use the `Collator` sample, you will succeed.

Comment: I've edited the post to clarify some bits. However, the question is a little unclear. Can you post the (Java?) code that you're using when sorting the text?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
val sortedList = yourCollection.sortedWith(Comparator { s1, s2 ->
                        Collator.getInstance(Locale("vi", "VN")).compare(s1.wardName, s2.wardName)
                    })
```