# sort results in ascending return in the form A, a, B, b... in Java

Tags: java, list, collections, comparator, comparable

I want to sort the List on name property

And the sort should be in ascending like A, a, B, b ... in java

It would be great if someone helps me in this.

For example

```
package corejava.compare;

import java.util.Comparator;

public class FirstNameSorter implements Comparator<Employee>{

     @Override
     public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
         return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
     }
}
```

And I have used this  comparator as below:

```
Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "aTestName", "dLastName", 34);
Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "A", "pLastName", 30);
Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "T", "sLastName", 31);
Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "D", "zLastName", 25);
Employee e5 = new Employee(5, "b", "zLastName", 25);

List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employees.add(e2);
employees.add(e3);
employees.add(e1);
employees.add(e4);
employees.add(e5);

Collections.sort(employees, new FirstNameSorter());

// Sorted by firstName
System.out.println(employees);
```

then I got the following output:

```
A
D
T
b
```

But, I want the following output:

```
A
b
D
T
```

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Does it matter if result will be `A, a, b` instead of `a, A, b`? Should uppercase always be before its corresponding lowercase (like A before a, B before b)?

Comment: Yes, upper case should be first like A, a, B, b

Comment: Your current comparator compares lexicographically, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order), so it obviously is not what you want. You need a more sophisticated approach for your comparator. For example, first compare based on ignoring the case (for example by lowercasing everything). And if two elements are equal according to that, compare them lexicographically (since that orders uppercase before lowoercase). If done right, the comparator can be probably 1 to 3 lines and also be created using the new modern methods.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Zabuza mentioned in a comment, the ordering you want is *almost* case-insensitive alphabetical, but not quite, since you want upper & lowercase characters to be grouped together when they're the same letter.

You can accomplish this by adding simply lower-casing the first names and comparing them, with a separate check to revert to a pure lexicographical ordering if the lower-cased check shows a match:

e.g.

```
public class FirstNameSorter implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        int precheck = o1.getFirstName().toLowerCase().compareTo(o2.getFirstName().toLowerCase());
        return precheck != 0 ? precheck : o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Aa", "dLastName", 34);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "b", "pLastName", 30);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "Bb", "sLastName", 31);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "C", "zLastName", 25); It is giving me output Aa,b,Bb,C but output should be Aa,Bb,b,C

Comment: I want upper case letter should come first.

Answer (score 1):

### **Update** (bugFix):

**Problem**:
Original solution using only `caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder` would order `a` and `Aa` as `[a, Aa]` instead of expected `[Aa, a]`.

**Cause**:
`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` only considers as equal strings with same length like `a` and `A` OR `aA` and `Aa`, which is condition for later provided by `thenComparing` comparator representing lexical order to work. But since `a` and `Aa` have different length they will not be additionally sorted by that lexical order which would place `Aa` before `a`.

**Solution**:
To fix this problem we can create Comparator which will manually iterate over "common" indexes of two strings and compare their corresponding characters using created earlier `caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrde` (from original answer below). By comparing single characters we are sure that these will have same length which should solve the problem and let us apply order `A < a < B < b < C < c < ...`:

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = (s1, s2) -> {
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
        int compare = caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder 
                .compare(s1.substring(i, i + 1), s2.substring(i, i + 1));
        if (compare != 0) return compare;
    }
    return Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length());
};

//DEMO:
String[] arr = {"a","A","aA","Aa","a","aA","bb","b","Bb","bB","aB"};
Arrays.sort(arr, myComparator);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

//Output:
//[A, Aa, a, a, aA, aA, aB, Bb, b, bB, bb]
```

---

## Original answer

For English only characters you can use Comparator

```
Comparator<String> caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder = String
            .CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER
            .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

which first sorts words regardless of their case like `b,c,a,A` -> `a,A,b,c`. `.thenComparing` provides way to order elements considered as equal like `a` and `A` in a way where `A` will be placed before `a` (which is natural ordering of string elements)

---

But if names can hold non-English characters (like in Polish `Ą,ą` which should be placed between `A,a` and `B,b`) we can't use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` because it would place non-English characters after English ones. For case like this we need solution described at [Sort List of Strings with Localization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12889760) like

```
Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pl", "PL")); //set locale of supported characters
coll.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
Comparator<Object> caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder = coll
        .thenComparing((o1, o2) -> o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString()));
```

Demo (with support of Polish characters):

```
String[] arr = {"cC","Cc","cc","CC", "ab","aB","Ab","AB", "ą", "Ą"};
Arrays.sort(arr, caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output: `[AB, Ab, aB, ab, Ą, ą, CC, Cc, cC, cc]`

If you want to sort collection of `Employee` instances based on property accessed via `getFirstName` you can use `caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder` Comparator like

```
Collections.sort(employees, Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName, caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder));
```

which can also be written as

```
employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getFirstName, caseInsensitiveThenNaturalOrder));
```

Comment: Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Aa", "dLastName", 34);
        Employee e5 = new Employee(1, "a", "dLastName", 34);
        Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "b", "pLastName", 30);
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "Bb", "sLastName", 31);
        Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "C", "zLastName", 25); it is giving me output a, Aa, b, Bb, C but I want output Aa, a, Bb, b, C

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "D", "a", "b", "B", "T");
        list.sort(comparator());
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static Comparator<? super String> comparator() {
        return (Comparator<String>) (leftString, rightString) -> {
            if (leftString.length() == rightString.length()) {
                for (int index = 0; index < leftString.length(); index++) {
                    final String leftChar = leftString.substring(index, index + 1);
                    final String rightChar = rightString.substring(index, index + 1);
                    if (!leftChar.equals(rightChar)) {
                        if (leftChar.toUpperCase().equals(rightChar.toUpperCase())) {
                            if (leftChar.equals(leftChar.toLowerCase()) && 
                                    rightChar.equals(rightChar.toUpperCase())) {
                                return 1;
                            } else {
                                return -1;
                            }
                        } else {
                            return leftChar.toUpperCase()
                                    .compareTo(rightChar.toUpperCase());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return 0;
            } else {
                return (leftString.length() > rightString.length()) ? -1 : +1;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[A, a, B, b, D, T]
```